# Alternative to fopen and include for opening and selecting from a txt file

Tags: php, optimization, fopen

i have the following code and i'm using it to select lines from txt file, the problem is that at high traffic this code cause my server to die...
It's there an alternative to open a txt file and select from it without high load?

```
<?php
include('txt/file.txt');
$content = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
$lines = preg_split("/\r\n|\n|\r/", $content);
for ( $i = 0; $i <= 15; $i++ ) {
$line= $lines[array_rand($lines)];
echo "<a href =\"/".$line."\"><h2>".$line."</h2></a> ";
} ?>
```

Comment: Have you seen the [`file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) method?

Comment: yes, but no difference...